# What is the best way to implicitly extract someone's location from a text message sent from his/her phone to an app?

Tags: geolocation, twilio

I am working on an app that needs to figure out someone's location in order to say buy a coffee from the Starbucks closest to them.

The app currently uses the Twilio API to receive a text from someone's phone and act on it.  The app can get the number and possibly the zip code if available from the text message; however, is there a more reliable way to get someone's location to accurately determine the closest Starbucks to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and the zip code is not reliable. It is an approximation based on area code.

Possible look at WhatsApp but not heavily used in some countries.

[Can I share my location or receive location information on WhatsApp?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052128874-Can-I-share-my-location-or-receive-location-information-on-WhatsApp-)